# how to calculate vehicle speed using mathematics and Image processing?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, physics, recreational-mathematics, parameter-estimation, image-processing

[image: actual detected vehicle(left side car in the image)] [image: Front and Side view]

**i am doing my project in image processing**.using segmentation i have detected the moving part(i.e the car) in the video successfully.

But now **i want to calculate speed of vehicle.**
in the above figure  i have added car positons at different time loaction captured in the video frames also its front view and side view.using frame rate i can calculate the time elapsed by vehicle to cover some distance.

**But i have one difficulty, as the vehicle goes away its size goes down also we can’t use linear scale to compute the distance** 
For this can anybody help me for distance computation? i am have added the image so that u can get an idea about it..
thank u

Comment: What's the model for how 3-D space projects onto the camera's focal plane?

Comment: @AnonSubmitter sir we can convrt the video frames into gray or binary frame and then perform processing on it.

Comment: Have you even bothered to try looking for answers with a search engine first? [The first hit from google](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the basis of the poles for calibration. They are at coordinates $$(X+kU, Y+kV, Z+kW)$$ for increasing $k$, where $(U, V, W)$ is the vector between two poles.

After perspective transformation, the projected coordinates are
$$(f\frac{X+kU}{Z+kW},f\frac{Y+kV}{Z+kW})=(\frac{x+ku}{1+kw}, \frac{y+kv}{1+kw}).$$
There are five unknowns, the coordinates of three points will be enough to find them.

Answer (score -1):

The height of an object is more or less related inversely with the distance to the observer's eyes. At least, that is a calculation that looks nominally right in a raycaster game I wrote.

Comment: @FundThmCalculusis sir,is there any other way to calculate speed vehicle using image processing or using mathematical trigonometry?? thank u

Comment: Easy: police radar gun. ;) Radar guns work on the Doppler shift effect, which is a pretty awesome solution.

Comment: @FubdThmCalculus Sir u are right but my project is based on image processing.please give me answer related to image processing..